convex function of martingale
I read this proposition in LeGall's "Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus."  Two questions:  Why does he need $f$ to be nonnegative-- why not just require $f(X_t)\in L^1$? also, dont you at least need $X_t$ to be $L^1$ or at least bounded from one direction or something?


You are right. $f$ need not be non-negative.

Indeed, as mentioned in https://almostsuremath.com/2009/12/06/martingales-and-elementary-integrals/, one can simply assume convexity and integrability:
Lemma 3 If $X$ is a martingale and $f\colon{\mathbb R}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ is a convex function such that $f(X)$ is integrable, then, $f(X)$ is a submartingale.
The proof is simply Jensen's inequality.
